# issues in the proof of master theorem

Tags: math, proof, master-theorem

I am reading the book *CLRS(Introduction To Alglorithms , 3rd edition)* , and find there seems to be a error in the proof of master theorem . In page 104 , in order to extend the proof to all integer, it use one inequation which seems to be incorrect. On the book it said that:

> Our first goal is to determine the depth k such that nk is a constant.
>   Using the inequality [x]<=x+1, we obtain

[x] here means the ceiling of x , it is obvious that `[x] < x+1` , not `[x] <= x+1` . Besides , in page 54 , there is another inequality confirm what I think

```
x -1 <  flooring(x) <= x <= ceiling(x) < x+1
```

Anyone can help to clarify this , why they are conflict ? if this inequality  is incorrect then whole the proof won't be correct

Comment: Usually, the Gauß bracket [x] denotes the integer part of a number, i.e., the next smallest integer, or floor(x). But still, x-1<[x] <=x<[x]+1. But obviously, [x]<=x+1 is also true, even if the equality case is never assumed.

Comment: Hi LutzL , really thanks , you remmind me the meaning of notation <= , I have asked a friend in mathematical major and he explain that there are 2 cases in that notation (equal or less than ) , any case satisfy then the inequality will be correct .further more ,if  a<b is true , we can conclude that a <= b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split to two cases:

1. `[x] > x` ---> `[x] < x+1` (trivial, and I think you agree with it)
2. `[x] = x` ---> `[x]+1 = x + 1` ---> `[x] < x+1`

Similarly for `x-1 < floor(x)`, split to two cases:

1. `floor(x) < x` ---> `floor(x) > x-1`
2. `floor(x) = x` ---> `floor(x) - 1 = x - 1` ---> `floor(x) > x-1`

So, in the last equation - all is left is `floor(x)<=c<=ceil(x)` - which is pretty much directly from their definition, and from the above two claims we get that:

```
x -1 <  flooring(x) <= x <= ceiling(x) < x+1
```

Comment: thx guy , you are right , and I didn't understand  the mathmetical logic meaning of <= notation just now .